# SQL: in calculation, I want the result to be 0, not null

Tags: php, sql, null

I have a SQL query in PHP that recalculates the average rating when the user cancels his vote:

```
$delete_vote = $conn->prepare("UPDATE table SET 
                    votes = votes - 1, 
                    total_value = total_value - :recall_vote, 
                    average = (total_value * 10) / (total_votes * 10)
                    WHERE id=id");
```

The problem is with the recalculation of the average vote. Even if I set the default value for the column 'total_value' and for 'average' as zero, if the query in question has only one vote, and that vote is being recalled, the average value will be set to null instead of 0, as I wish it to be. One possible way of solving this would be to retrieve these two values from the database, check if they're null, and then have them changed to 0--but that's a bit of a hassle. So instead, I want to know if there's a simpler solution.

Another thing I've tried is to add a zero to the calculation, hoping that the null would convert to 0:

```
$vote_count = $conn->prepare("UPDATE table SET 
                total_votes = (0 + total_votes) + 1
```

That doesn't work either. Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: how about not taking a nullable field, and taking a float/int with default value 0? I do not get your point..

Comment: Is it possible to have zero `total_votes`? This will result in a *Division by Zero* error, maybe your DBMS returns a NULL instead. Try `average = COALESCE((total_value * 10) / (total_votes * 10), 0)`

Comment: can you not set it to have a value of '0' when NULL?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: The simplest solution is to drop the average column and calculate it when required.

Comment: = coalesce(expression, 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using PHP, I'm assuming you're using MySQL with it. But I think every RDBMS has a similar function... In MySQL you can define a fallback value for when a value is `NULL`. If the value isn't `NULL`, it will return the original value:

```
IFNULL(something, 0)
```

**Besides that, slightly offtopic maybe;** I usually try to avoid denormalisation like you did by saving the average - which in most cases can be calculated when querying the database. But this depends on the situation.

Comment: Can add that the line `average = (total_value * 10) / (total_votes * 10)` can be written as `average = (IFNULL(total_value, 0) * 10) / (IFNULL(total_votes, 1) * 10)` to take care of the 'Divide by 0' problem. Was waiting for the RDBMS to post this exact answer :)

Comment: My bad, I should've made it clear that I'm using MySql. It seems that this solution works similar to the coalesce solution. However, even with Bernd's addendum, the average is calculated to Null. But for now, this isn't a problem for me, because at least this time, the average is recalculated correctly as soon as someone votes on the query. Btw, I do save the average in the database--this is an update when the vote is being recalled. :)

I've looked into the differences between IFNULL and coalesce and, for this solution, I'm going with IFNULL. Thanks to all who informed me of the rest. +1

Answer (score 1):

I totally do not understand your `where` clause -- which would almost always evaluate to true.

The correct syntax to use is the ANSI standard `COALESCE()` or `CASE` which are available in almost all databases.  You could write this as:

```
UPDATE table
    SET votes = votes - 1, 
        total_value = total_value - :recall_vote, 
        average = COALESCE((total_value * 10) / NULLIF(total_votes * 10, 0), 0)
    WHERE id = $id -- something other than `id`
```

I think I would be inclined to be explicit:

```
UPDATE table
    SET votes = votes - 1, 
        total_value = total_value - :recall_vote, 
        average = (CASE WHEN total_votes > 0
                        THEN total_value / total_votes
                        ELSE 0
                   END)
    WHERE id = $id -- something other than `id`
```

By the way, why are you multiplying by 10 in both the numerator and denominator?  Seems unnecessary.